# Is there any way that we can get idea about the Finger details of Fingerprint authentication?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I am developing one application, in that application i want to add some restriction based on Finger print login.

Let's assume i have added two Fingerprint in my device.

```
1) Left hand index finger 
2) Right hand index finger
```

Is there any way so i can get idea about which finger has been used for the authentication, i mean to say i am logged in my app using left index finger or right index finger.

`FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way so i can get idea about which finger has been used for the authentication

No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, you can't register fingerprint or access the data but only can check the enrollment with code below

```
//Check whether the device has a fingerprint sensor//
    if (!mFingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
        // If a fingerprint sensor isn’t available, then inform the user that they’ll be unable to use your app’s fingerprint functionality//
        textView.setText("Your device doesn't support fingerprint authentication");
    }
    //Check whether the user has granted your app the USE_FINGERPRINT permission//
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // If your app doesn't have this permission, then display the following text//
        Toast.makeText(EnterPinActivity.this, "Please enable the fingerprint permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //Check that the user has registered at least one fingerprint//
    if (!mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
        // If the user hasn’t configured any fingerprints, then display the following message//
        Toast.makeText(EnterPinActivity.this, "No fingerprint configured. Please register at least one fingerprint in your device's Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //Check that the lockscreen is secured//
    if (!mKeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
        // If the user hasn’t secured their lockscreen with a PIN password or pattern, then display the following text//
        Toast.makeText(EnterPinActivity.this, "Please enable lockscreen security in your device's Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hello Moeen, thanks for the Answer. I know about the enrollment but i want the specific finger print details to differentiate.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no way to handle this.